# How to run Docker in Virtualbox mac OS Sierra?

Tags: mac, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I have a GitHub project that uses [Docker](http://docker.com) to create virtualizations.

My teammates all have Mac computers, but I have a Windows computer, forcing me to use a VM.

When I try to run Docker on the VM, it says my processor is incompatible, even though I have Virtualization turned on, and the Paravirtualization setting set to "Minimal" for mac OS. Is there any way to fix something like this?

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wz4p.jpg)

Answer (score -1):

'''

Because of the security layers and kext in the OS - one would not be able to create anykind of virtualization with the virtualbox driver (not hyperkit one), so minikube and or kubernetes deployments would most likely fail (if you kept on updating your Unix : ) ), however security is security! (for all haters:  RHEL/Centos did even worse when going from 6 to 7 ).

Why even (Evan? (big grin)) Bother (lame joke heh.)

VirtualBox driver is faster. Much more and it's highly recommended to use that one instead of hyperkit. (concurency sir!)

But wait - why can't I just install? Oh because kernel does not neccesarily allow for all different Kinds of System Calls from who - knows - where  (smile)

That said, It will not necessarily work out of the box when you put "virtualbox" string into environments file, so first extra step would be
Making sure you have all minikubes stopped deleted and so on. If you run docker-machine with failed virtualbox there - remove it.

also go with: `rm -rf ~/.minikube`

1. Now time for Checking some dope stuff up, yay! After typing 
   " kextstat | grep -i box " command you may notice some loaded plugins

   - if you do, then we need to unload these extensions first! If tou don't - go to step 2 (go to step 2 anyways! ha!)

Example:

MacBook-Pro: /Library/Application Support/VirtualBox: $ kextstat | grep -i box

2. Navigate to that  "/Library/Application Support/VirtualBox" and list the folder.

You should see sth like: LaunchDaemons VBoxDrv.kext VBoxNetAdp.kext VBoxNetFlt.kext VBoxUSB.kext

Type (being in that folder):

`` for i in ` ls | grep -i vbox ` ; do sudo kextunload $i -r "$(pwd)" ; done ``

3. We need to Allow from aywhere for a moment of Reinstallation process for virtualbox itself.

having said so go with :

`sudo spctl --master-disable`
and it should disable the gatekeeper Guard and make the option for Allowing from anywhere being Selectable{} :)
 -> Firewall Security and Privacy Settings (os x)

Unlock, provide your root pass and select Allow from anywhere (it will be needed during virtualbox installation)

4. Next, Uninstall and Install the actual virtualbox - as new as possible (>= 5. ).  If installation told you it's failed - no worries. We'll hack you into. Firstly go to that point 3 and allow for Oracle corp :D (I had to click there again despite having it allowed from anywhere (btw, remember the plugins and kext?)
5. Make sure you're in the folder you need to be (as in before example) and load these by mapping to proper folder's contents.

`` for i in ` ls | grep -i vbox ` ; do sudo kextload $i -r "$(pwd)" ; done ``

6. Now, you have to go Privacy Settings and Firewall Again, you'll see that Oracle America asks for your attention! Click Allow or whatever that button is.

After it's done you're good to go.

7. To Test it:

`docker-machine create -d virtualbox virtualbox`
`docker-machine start virtualbox`
`docker-machine ssh virtualbox.`
You should see:
[Dope!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbRUX.png)

That is the exactly same result as it was launched by the virtualbox itself with boot2docker image!

How cool is that?

8. oh, forgot the most important part:

`minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox`

Enjoy :)
'''